# ¿Cómo cargar el javascript de bootstrap con un deploy de capistrano?

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Tengo una aplicación muy vieja, en **Ruby 2.5.5** y **Rails 4.2.8**, no la pude subir mas de versión en Ruby ni en Rails.

El **boostrap** de JavaScript corre bien en mi máquina local, al hacer el deploy con Capistrano, me di cuenta que no carga el **boostrap** de JavaScript.

Mi *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require select2-full
//= require underscore
//= require coffee_routes
//= require gmaps/google
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts
//= require fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint
//= require_tree .
```

mi *Capfile*

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Mi *config/deploy.rb*

```
server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@hub:qwerty/abc.git'
set :application,     'abc'
set :user,            'ubuntu'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
set :branch,        :main
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  # before :start, :make_dirs
  before 'deploy:starting', 'puma:make_dirs'
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/main`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/main"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  # after  :finishing,    :restart
end
```

Estoy atascado :(

¿Alguna idea que me puede estar faltando?